# Need help optimizing a loop with 3 dataframes

Tags: python, performance, loops, pandas, optimization

First dataframe : inj_2014 (35040, 991), in which the column references correspond to what is called EAN.

```
          Date                 541448860005060119 541448860003851078 ...
0         2014-01-01 00:00:00                 0.0                0.0
1         2014-01-01 00:15:00                 0.1                0.0
...
```

Second dataframe : db (1125,17). Here the EAN are regrouped in one column. There are more lines than 991 because it corresponds to contract specifications : if the contracts ends in february 2014 and starts again in march 2014, there are 2 lines in the df. The columns sd and ed correspond to the starting date and ending date

```
                    EAN          sd            ed  ...
0    541448860008422181  2014-07-02    2017-01-03
1    541449200002077458  2012-01-04    2014-05-07
...
```

Third dataframe : prices (1125,9). Basically each EAN has different price specifications, that changes throughout the year (Q1-Q2-Q3-Q4) and the time (peak-offpeak)

```
     Q1_peak  Q1_off_peak  ... Q4_off_peak                  EAN
0    82.0264      56.9196          61.9826   541448860008422181
1    85.2736      57,8456          58,7564   541449200002077458
...
```

What I want to do : multiply the number (ie the injection) in the inj_2014 by the price and put it in a new dataframe, taking into account:

- the fact that the injection should not be calculated if the date is not within the bounds of the contract (or return 0)
- the fact that 2 different contracts may have the same EAN and therefore 2 different columns should be the output (with for example EAN_1 for the more recent contract)
- the fact that the price by which the injection should be multiplied depends both on the date AND the EAN

I already wrote a few helpfull functions :

```
def in_contrat(date, sd, ed):
    '''True if date within date limits'''
    if sd < date < ed:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def price_name(date, dates_2014): #dates_2014 = list of the quarter limit dates
    '''returns price name corresponding to the given date'''
    if date < date_2014[1]:
        if peak(date):
            return 'Q1_peak'
        else:
            return 'Q1_off_peak'
    elif date < date_2014[2]:
        if peak(date):
            return 'Q2_peak'
    ...

def in_contrat(date, sd, ed):
    '''True if date within date limits'''
    if sd < date < ed:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_index(df, test):
    '''returns list with index occurences of the specific EAN number in the db'''
    index = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df['EAN'][i] == test:
            index.append(i)
    return index
```

So with this material I tried to write my master function :

```
def daily_calculation(inj_2014, db, prices):
    list_EAN = []
    for i in range(len(db)):
        EAN = db['EAN'][i]
        if EAN not in list_EAN:
            list_EAN.append(EAN)
            index = get_index(prices, EAN)[0]
        else : 
            index = get_index(prices, EAN)[1]
        for j in range(len(inj_2014)):
            date = inj_2014['Date'][j]
            name = price_name(date, dates_2014)
            EBIQ = prices[name][index]
            valeur_injection = inj_2014[EAN][j]/4000
            if in_contrat(date, db['sd'][i], db['ed'][i]) and inj_2014[EAN][j] != 0:
                results.set_value(j, EAN, (valeur_injection)*EBIQ)
            else:
                results.set_value(j, EAN, 0)
    return results
```

So the thing is, this seems to work. However, considering the time that it took me to compute only the first column, it should take me between 80 and 100h to get my results, and they might even be wrong. I can deal with a few days run-find mistake-run-find misake-... but not a few months.

I'm sure there is a way to optimize this loop a gain a tremendous amount of time (I already managed to get from 200h to 100h). However, I am quite new with python/pandas/etc and I do not have the experience to optimize it myself ; this is kind of a desperate call.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to write an exact answer without more information, but here is an attempt.

**First**, stack `inj_2014` to put column names into a new column called `EAN`:

```
inj_stacked = inj_2014.set_index('Date') \
                      .stack() \ 
                      .reset_index(drop=False) \
                      .rename(columns={'level_1': 'EAN', 0: 'injection'})
```

**Second**, merge with `db` (for prices I recommend a lookup):

```
inj_stacked = inj_stacked.merge(db, on='EAN', how='outer')
```

Note: you will have to experiment with the different values of `how`. Above is my best guess.

**Third**, vectorize the operations you apply:

```
inj_stacked['in_contrat'] = (inj_stacked['Date'] > inj_stacked['sd']) \
                          & (inj_stacked['Date'] < inj_stacked['ed'])

inj_stacked['price_name'] = inj_stacked['Date'].apply(price_name, 
                                                      args=(dates_2014,))
```

**Fourth**, lookup prices:

```
inj_stacked['price'] = prices.set_index('EAN').lookup(
    inj_stacked['EAN'], 
    inj_stacked['price_name']).values
```

This is all untested, please adapt as required.